# ED Code First One to Many Relationship Issue - ASP Identity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I'm configuring a database for ASP Identity and I've hit a snag.

I'm looking to create a `One to Many` relationship between two tables, which are `ApplicationUser` & `OrganisationUnit`.

An OrganisationUnit can have multiple `ApplicationUsers`, with an `ApplicationUser` only belonging to one `OrganisationUnit`

When I add a migration and update the database I get an error during execution :-

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.OrganisationUnits_OrganisationUnitRefId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "DefaultConnection", table
>   "dbo.OrganisationUnits", column 'OrganisationUnitId'.

Here are the tables I'm trying to create :-

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Forename { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public Guid OrganisationUnitId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrganisationUnitId")]
        public virtual OrganisationUnit OrganisationUnit { get; set; }

    }



  public class OrganisationUnit
        {

            public OrganisationUnit()
            {
                ApplicationUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
            }


            public Guid Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string Telephone { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        }
```

In my seed method for the Configuration.cs have the following code :-

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

            var ou = new OrganisationUnit()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "Group1",
                Telephone = "1234567890",
            };

            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "SuperPowerUser",
                Email = "derek@rdsadfasdf.com",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                Forename = "Derek",
                Surname = "Rivers",
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3),
                OrganisationUnitId = ou.Id
            };

            userManager.Create(user, "MySuperP@ssword!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try :

```
        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "SuperPowerUser",
            Email = "derek@rdsadfasdf.com",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            Forename = "Derek",
            Surname = "Rivers",
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3),
            OrganisationUnit = ou
        };
```

With your syntax (only provinding a FK) you assume that the Organisation exists.